# Programa para remover APENAS uma cópia de valores duplicados de uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, revisão-de-código

Escreva um método rem() que aceite como entrada uma lista contendo, possivelmente, valores duplicados, e retorne uma cópia da lista em que uma cópia de cada valor duplicado seja removida.
O que eu fiz:

```
    def rem(lista):
    i = 0
    while i <= len(lista):
        # print(lista[i])
        if lista.count(i) >= 2:
            lista.remove(i)
        i += 1
    print(lista)

lista = [3,4,5,6,5,5]
#lista = [4,4]
rem(lista)
```

Exemplo de saída:

```
rem([2, 4, 2, 4, 4])
[2, 4, 4]
```

O código funciona para a lista `[3,4,5,6,5,5]` mas não para `[4,4]`. 
O que fiz de errado?

Answer (score 1):

Caso querias remover apenas 1 cópia de cada elemento duplicado, podes usar um `set` e ir verificando se já "viste" esse valor ou não:

```
def rem(lista):
    seen = set([])
    for i, x in enumerate(lista):
        if x in seen:
            lista.pop(i)
            break
        seen.add(x)
    return lista

lista = [3,4,5,6,5,5]
print(rem(lista))
#[3, 4, 5, 6, 5]
```

Comment: A sua solução não funciona, pois tem que remover apenas uma cópia duplicada. A saida de (rem(lista)) deve ser [3,4,6,5,5]

Comment: Queres remover apenas 1 vez cada valor duplicado?

Comment: isso! Apenas uma cópia deve ser removida!

Comment: Mas em alguma posição especifica? Tens de remover o primeiro duplicado ou pode ser o ultimo?

Comment: pode ser qualquer um!

Comment: não entendo porque negativaram a pergunta! Eu tentei fazer!

Comment: Ok, não tinha percebido isso de inicio. Vê agora a correção.

Comment: Não entendi algumas coisas no código. Poderia, por favor, comentar?

Comment: Claro. O que é que não entendeste?

Comment: Por Exemplo:   seen = set([])

Comment: Isso incializa a variável que vai guardar os elementos da lista à medida que vão sendo 'vistos'. O tipo `set` é um tipo de objeto que não permite ter duplicados.

Comment: Baseado na sua resposta, tentei fazer um novo código. O que acha dele?

Answer (score -1):

```
def rem(lista):
    i = 0
    seen = set()
    nova_lista = lista.copy()
    while i < len(lista):
        # print(lista[i])

        if lista.count(lista[i]) >= 2:

            if lista[i] not in seen:
                nova_lista.remove(lista[i])
                seen.add(lista[i])


        i += 1
        print(f"seen :{seen}, nova_lista:{nova_lista}")
    print()
    print(nova_lista)


# lista = [3,4,5,6,5,5]
#lista = [4,4]
#lista = [3,4,5,6,5,5,5,6,6,3,6,4]
lista = [2,4,2,4,4]
rem(lista)
```

Comment: Explica a resposta, por favor, senão é somente um código avulso sem nexo.